aiohttp ошибка при создании вк бота (vkbottle)
У меня есть ВК бот и вот в этой строке
bot = Bot(api=API(token=TOKEN, http_client=AiohttpClient(session=ClientSession(connector=TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)))))

у меня ошибка RuntimeError: no running event loop. Не могу понять почему. Версия python 3.10.5 Версия vkbottle: 4.3.11, так как если обновлюсь до последней версии, то будут еще и предупреждения
Полная ошибка
bot = Bot(api=API(token=TOKEN, http_client=AiohttpClient(session=ClientSession(connector=TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)))))

File "C:\Users\gamin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 826, in __init__ super().__init__(

File "C:\Users\gamin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 245, in __init__ loop = loop or asyncio.get_running_loop() RuntimeError: no running event loop

Токен и все что нужно прописано

«no running event loop» — какое слово непонятно в тексте ошибки?

Нужен более полный код, одной строки недостаточно
